# Problema con etiqueta requiered

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo.

```js
window.onload = function () {
 var placa = document.getElementById('placa');
 placa.onblur = Validar;
}
function Validar(){ 
 var placa = document.getElementById('placa');
 placa.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  this.setCustomValidity('');
 });
 placa.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
 // Required
  if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
   this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digitar la placa');
  }
 });
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/plantilla_gral.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/marcas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
   <h2>Registrar nuevo propietario</h2>
   <div class ="contenedor-input">
    <input type = "text" id = "placa" name = "placa" placeholder = "Ingresar placa" class = "input-100" required />
     class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar"/>
   </div>  
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Se supone que cuando la persona no digita nada en el campo de la placa debe aparecer una nube con el mensaje que le puse, pero al probar el html sin el script me doy cuenta de que la etiqueta de required no esta funcionando y la verdad no se por que?

agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Te refieres este mensaje del required? http://prntscr.com/kgcln4 De ser así, quizá debas borrar la caché del navegador para que se te cargue la página de nuevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/plantilla_gral.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/marcas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
   <h2>Registrar nuevo propietario</h2>
   <div class ="contenedor-input">
    <input type = "text" id = "placa" name = "placa" placeholder = "Ingresar placa" class = "input-100" required />
    <input type="submit" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar"/>
   </div>  
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ami me funciona bien actualiza tu navegador y borra la capcha **alt + f5**

Comment: No me funciona cuando lo pruebo con el coidgo completo